# How to make <a href> clickable without text

Tags: html, css

I have a table which contain a bunch of links. The links contain no text, instead I'm using the css attribute `content` to define the look of the links (in this case, the links contain the symbols of facebook, instagram and twitter). So far it looks like it should, but I cannot click on them. I want to avoid using `&nbsp;`, so what could I do?

Here's my HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="fblink">
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ladygaga" target="_blank"></a>
           </td>
            <td class="twlink">
                <a href="http://twitter.com/LadyGaga" target="_blank"></a>
           </td>
            <td class="iglink">
                <a href="http://instagram.com/ladygaga" target="_blank"></a>
            </td>
         </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my CSS:

```
table{
   border-collapse: seperate;
   border-spacing: 10px 0;
}

.fblink{
   background: blue;
}
.fblink:before{ 
   content:'\f30c';
}


.twlink{
   background: lightblue;
 }
.twlink:before{ 
   content:'\f309';
 }

.iglink{
   background: red;

 }
.iglink:before{ 
   content:'\f32d';
 }
```

Can someone help me out? I created a Fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/Qf99d/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well currently the links are not containing anything. You could set them to `display:block` and give them some width/height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must put something in link tag so for example you can add icon tag inside link like this:

```
<td>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ladygaga" target="_blank"><i class="fblink"></i></a>
           </td>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are adding the pseudo elements in the wrong place...they should be inside the anchor links instead of the table cells

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/Qf99d/9/)

**CSS**

```
table{
    border-collapse: seperate;
    border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
tr td a  {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:100%; /* make anchor full widths */
}
a:before {
    color:white;

}

.fblink{
    background: blue;
}
.fblink a:before{   
    content:'\f30c'; /* now inside anchor */
}


.twlink{
    background: lightblue;
}
.twlink a:before{   
    content:'\f309';
}

.iglink{
    background: red;

}
.iglink a:before{   
    content:'\f32d';
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that some browsers, especially mobile browsers, don't like pseudo-elements in links, and don't make them properly clickable.

Answer (score 3):

Don´t forget: Using `table` elements for layout purposes is considered a bad practice. Use CSS for layout.

If you want to have the whole table cell clickable and not change your markup, you could go with something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qf99d/8/

CSS:

```
table{
    border-collapse: seperate;
    border-spacing: 10px 0;
}

.fblink a, .twlink a, .iglink a  {
    display: inline-block;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fblink{
    background: blue;
}
.fblink a:before{   
    content:'\f30c';    
}

.twlink{
    background: lightblue;
}

.twlink a:before{   
    content:'\f309';
}

.iglink{
    background: red;

}
.iglink a:before{   
    content:'\f32d';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a related side-note that's worth mentioning:
If you are considering using an `<a>` tag that has no describable text as its content (like an image or an icon), then you must keep Accessibility in mind. I recommend either including a `title` attribute or an `aria-label` attribute.
More info: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/1.1/link-name

Answer (score 1):

Simply insert the images you want to be able to click on between the `<a>` brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert a dummy DIV in the `<a>` tag if you don't want to use any `<img>`:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/ladygaga" target="_blank"><div style="width:1em; height:1em; display:inline-block"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS set the width of the anchor tag to the size of its parent, i.e. display:block; Whole table cell is clickable than.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and height of the anchor to the same width and height of the background image.  The anchor sizes according to its content (of which there is none) unless overridden.

I checked your fiddle.  Make sure the Anchor is sized, not just the containing TD.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I know how to do this off the top of my head.  Like listed above, you could set the image inside the a tags or you could do an image map.  Personally, I would just put the links like this.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/ladygaga" target="_blank"><img src="File Here" /></a>
```

And so on.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect an href to redirect you if you have nothing to click on [mod](https://www.alightmotionapps.com) .

You could use jQuery after the page has loaded, something like this:

```js
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#the aHref").html("\f30c");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a  clickable without displaying any visible text, you can achieve this by using CSS to hide the text. Here's how you can do it

Html:

```
<a href="URL_HERE" class="hidden-link"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden-link {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

In the HTML code, replace "URL_HERE" with the actual URL you want to link to. The class="hidden-link" assigns the CSS class to the  element.

In the CSS code, the .hidden-link class is defined with the following properties:

**display: block;** makes the link a block-level element so that it occupies space on the webpage.

**width: 0;** and **height: 0;** set the dimensions of the link to zero, making it effectively invisible.

**overflow: hidden;** ensures that any content inside the link [trafficridergames](https://trafficridergames.com/) same like a place code (in this case, the text) is hidden and does not overflow.

With these CSS properties, the link will be present on the webpage but won't display any visible text. When users click on the area occupied by the link, they will be redirected to the URL specified in the href attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You can't expect an href to redirect you if you have nothing to click on.

You could use jQuery after the page has loaded, something like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#theHref").html("\f30c");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

Use several   (Space character) between link tags like this

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/ladygaga" target="_blank">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: Read the post. "I want to avoid using &nbsp;"

Comment: Oops! sorry. Use an image with a width of 1px and height to any and a transparent png one. and set the width in the image tag.